# Why can I call an abstract class method in Python?

Tags: python

If I define an abstract class with an abstract method:

```
import abc


class A(abc.ABC):

    @classmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass
```

I can't instantiate it (as expected):

```
>>> A()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class A with abstract methods foo
```

But I can call its abstract method with no errors.

```
>> A.foo()
```

Is this behavior documented somewhere ?

Tested on Python 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: Official python docs about ABC: docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html
Info: www.python-course.eu/python3_abstract_classes.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is explicit about that.

Simply the documentation of a the `abstractmethod` decorator says:

> A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden.

And PEP 3119 says:

> A class containing at least one method declared with this decorator that hasn't been overridden yet cannot be instantiated.

and later

> **Implementation**: The `@abstractmethod` decorator sets the function attribute `__isabstractmethod__` to the value True. The `ABCMeta.__new__` method computes the type attribute `__abstractmethods__` as the set of all method names that have an `__isabstractmethod__` attribute whose value is true. It does this by combining the `__abstractmethods__` attributes of the base classes, adding the names of all methods in the new class dict that have a true `__isabstractmethod__` attribute, and removing the names of all methods in the new class dict that don't have a true `__isabstractmethod__` attribute. If the resulting `__abstractmethods__` set is non-empty, the class is considered abstract, and attempts to instantiate it will raise `TypeError`.

My interpretation of the implementation part is that `@abstractmethod` never prevents the method to be called but only say that that class cannot be instantiated and that a subclass will still be abstract unless it overrides all of its abstract methods.

So I would not say that it is *by design*, but it is at least an assumed side effect.

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is a `classmethod` and by [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) a class method can be called directly by the class itself.
By doing

```
In [3]: A.foo()
```

you are not instantiating the class `A`, rather you are just calling the function `foo` on class `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing `abc.ABC` indicates that class `A` cannot be instantiated directly.

The `@abc.abstractmethod` decorator forces a check on any subclass of `A` during type/name resolution. If `class subofA(A):` does not implement the decorated method, then an exception is raised.

Once type/name resolution is passed, the abstractmethod decorator does not prevent you from calling the method. After all, you aren't able to call the method without an instance, unless it is a class method.

By decorating `foo` with both `@classmethod` and `@abstractmethod` you, the developer, specify that `A.foo()` is safe to call without instantiating the class, but that anyone who subclasses `A` must implement an overriding method to preserve that behaviour.